# Python - KeyError: 'dpi'

Tags: python, keyerror

I have a python script that lists the metadata of photos inside a directory. It works however it is not fully working. When it runs I can get data from ~250 files then I get an error

This is the error:

```
  File "c:\Users\edward\OneDrive - ISC Industries\Summer Intern 2022\Scripts\metadata.py", line 22, in <module>
"Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
KeyError: 'dpi'
```

I am not sure why this is since it works for some files but there is over 17000 files so I would like for all of the data to be printed.

Here is the full script:

```
import json
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
import os
import os.path
import PIL
from pandas import json_normalize

PIL.Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 384000000
rootdir = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics"

newfile = newfile = open('meta.txt', 'w')
newfile.write("Filename                                     |  Image DPI                    | Image Height                  |   Image Width                 |   Image Format                |   Image Mode                  |   Image Frames                |\n")
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

# extract other basic metadata
info_dict = {
    "Filename": image.filename,
    "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
    "Image Height": image.height,
    "Image Width": image.width,
    "Image Format": image.format,
    "Image Mode": image.mode,
    "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
}

line = ""
for label, value in info_dict.items():
    line += f"|{str(value):<30} "  
line += " |"  
newfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems that some file(s) don't have dpi information.

Comment: is there a way to make it so it skips dpi for those files

Comment: The error is telling you that `info['dpi']` isn't available on some of your files. You could use a `try: except:` block to print out the names of files that don't have the info without stopping your code from executing

Comment: That depends on what `image` and `info` are. If it's a `dict`, you can use `.get` to get the `dpi` value, or `None` if it doesn't exist. If it's some other class, then it's anybody's guess.

Comment: I just updated the whole script, could you show me where to put the code to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `try` and `except` Just reuse your code:

```
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
try:
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir,file))

    # extract other basic metadata
    info_dict = {
        "Filename": os.path.basename(image.filename),
        "Image DPI": image.info['dpi'],
        "Image Height": image.height,
        "Image Width": image.width,
        "Image Format": image.format,
        "Image Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }

    line = ""
    for label, value in info_dict.items():
        line += f"|{str(value):<30} "  
    line += " |"  
    newfile.write(line + '\n')
except:
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir,file))

    # extract other basic metadata
    info_dict = {
        "Filename": os.path.basename(image.filename),
        "Image Height": image.height,
        "Image Width": image.width,
        "Image Format": image.format,
        "Image Mode": image.mode,
        "Frames in Image": getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
    }

    line = ""
    for label, value in info_dict.items():
        line += f"|{str(value):<30} "  
    line += " |"  
    newfile.write(line + '\n')
```